# Issue stubbing a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm working with CoreBluetooth, so in my unit tests I'm mocking all the CB objects so they return what I want. In one of my tests, I mock a CBPeripheral, and stub the delegate method like so:

```
[[[mockPeripheral stub] andReturn:device] delegate];
```

The device passed in is my wrapper object which holds on to the peripheral. Later in the test, I call a method on **device** which then checks:

```
NSAssert(_peripheral.delegate == self, @"Empty device");
```

This line is being asserted during the test because **_peripheral.delegate != self**.

I've debugged through, and made sure that **_peripheral** is an OCMockObject. Why isn't the stubbed method returning **device** when the assert checks the **_peripheral**'s delegate?

Here's the detailed code:

```
@interface Manager : NSObject
- (void)connectToDevice:(Device*)device;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)connectToDevice:(Device*)device {
    if([device checkDevice]) {
        /** Do Stuff */
    }
}

@end

@interface Device : NSObject {
    CBPeripheral _peripheral;
}
- (id)initWithPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral;
@end

@implementation Device

- (id)initWithPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {        
        _peripheral = peripheral;
        _peripheral.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)checkDevice {
    NSAssert(_peripheral.delegate == self, @"Empty device");
    return YES;
}

@end

@implementation Test

__block id peripheralMock;

beforeAll(^{
    peripheralMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[CBPeripheral class]];
});

//TEST METHOD
it(@"should connect", ^{
    Device *device = [[Device alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheralMock];

    [[[peripheralMock stub] andReturn:device] delegate];

    [manager connectToDevice:device];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this -- is this what you're doing?

```
@interface Bar : NSObject <CBPeripheralDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *peripheral;
- (void)peripheralTest;
@end

- (void)peripheralTest
{
    NSAssert(_peripheral.delegate == self, @"Empty device");
}

// In test class:    
- (void)testPeripheral
{
    Bar *bar = [Bar new];
    id peripheralMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:CBPeripheral.class];
    [[[peripheralMock stub] andReturn:bar] delegate];
    bar.peripheral = peripheralMock;
    [bar peripheralTest];
}
```

This test passes for me.

Comment: Pretty much, except there's an additional manger object in the process as well. I've updated the question with a more in depth code sample.

Comment: Ah, after some more careful debugging, it seems I was somehow running a second similar test before the original finished which used the shared mockPeripheral. After making the peripheral a local object, the tests passed. I'll accept your answer because it technically works for me now.